# Determine HDD inventory (current and possible) on FC6

Tags: fedora, hard-drive

I am running FC6 and am working to upgrade it.  In the process, I would like to add some additional HDD's.  How can I take inventory of the current drives I have and possible space for new internal drives.

The server is a Dell PowerEdge 860.

Comment: jon - this would be better suited to ServerFault.com as it is server administration related.

Comment: oops.  I thought I was posting to serverfault....  thx.

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking for total raw space available on the disks, smartctl, parted, and fdisk can show you that.

If you're looking for in-use, including on partitions that aren't mounted, gparted might be the way to go, though it isn't quite as automated / trivial.

Answer (score 0):

```
cat /proc/partitions
```

shows all disks/partitions detected by the kernel